# Standalone PYPI package/script

Tags: python, package, pypi

Probably the lack of my knowledge is the problem number 1 here :)
I am trying to create a standalone app to run on any OS with python.
Just for an example (youtube-dl).

I was going trough the tutorials how to package, but even when I do that, I am getting errors on the end of it :(

Whoever takes time to help me out is an ANGEL <3
p.s. the script does some NSFW work ;)

Was following this tut:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

The script is here:
https://github.com/mariosemes/PornHub-downloader-python

edit:
Creating a wheel:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Uploading to pypi test:

```
python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

Installed it on my system.

Trying to run it:

```
$phdler
```

And error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sema\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\sema\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\phdler.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'phdler' (c:\users\sema\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\phdler\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Add fist I like to say that this might get my personal question of the week. You might want to increase your chances by adding the error message, and the code **to the question** itself, and also ask a proper question.

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting please? The reason we ask is that failure could be due to any environmental issues unique to your computer, we would not be helping you find a solution otherwise.

Comment: I understand. I am sorry I didnt do it on the first. Here it is in the edited version. Thank you very much.

Comment: How does your `setup.py` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to publish single script/module to pypi, if so, you have to add them to `py_modules` argument in your `setup.py` and add some `entry_points` like this:

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    py_modules=['phdler','functions']
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "phdler=phdler:main",
        ]
    }
)
```